# Differentiate premium features from normal features

Tags: features, product-design, b2b, saas

**Context:** I am designing for a B2B SaaS product and we want to lock features with the following states for different users:

- Locked State: For free-plan users not having access to add-on features and they should be prompted with an option to upgrade their plan when they click on them.
- Available state: Normal state of features available to premium users and some features also available to free users
- Request Only: For users on an enterprise plan so they can request access to include certain features in their plan

I have attached an image of what I tried, our primary color is blue and I went with Indigo to showcase a locked feature along with a lock icon, but it's ot very differentiating.

I used indigo as it represents premium/luxury.

Can someone help me how to better differentiate it so it reduces user frustration?

**EDIT 1**
The issue with the current design is that we are using blue as a primary color and indigo is not very differentiating, which might confuse the users into thinking that it is also a normal feature and result in frustration.

Moreover, these state are to be designed for several features some of which have an icon on the left while some dont, so it's not very scalable to all the features. I hope that clears it.

[image]

Comment: Before the question gets close votes (it's a review request or at least opinion based), can you elaborate more on what is actually wrong with the current design? If it is: "It doesn't look nice", then the question is more suitable for graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The issue with the current design is that we are using blue as a primary color and indigo is not very differentiating, which might confuse the users into thinking that it is also a normal feature and result in frustration.

Moreover, these state are to be designed for several features some of which have an icon on the left while some dont, so it's not very scalable to all the features. I hope that clears it.

Comment: The code should check if the person is on the Free Trial and not even show buttons not relevant to it (or gray it out as not available in that version). As is, the bottom button is an invitation to buy credits and it's not clear that it works with the Free Trial. The color doesn't matter. The color by itself doesn't mean "Not available with free trial."

Comment: Can you list the different users and plans available? I am confused between the free plan, premium user and enterprise plan. The states are clear because you only need to show the locked features (for free plan users) and the requestable features (for enterprise plan users), but the types of users are not clear.